# What are places shown in this sticker that claims to be a silhouette of Bangalore (Karnataka, India) skyline?

Tags: india, sightseeing, south-india

I came across this image

[image: this image]

and was curious what the places were. I'm soon planning a visit to Bangalore and would like to visit these places.

Comment: Search Google Images for "Bangalore Temples" and you will find many pictures of these places.

Comment: I did and could not figure out what the blue temple like structure is. Everything else, I'm good.

Comment: I'd say the blue one is this: https://www.flickr.com/photos/mastababa/9214363645/in/photolist-f3f2hH-f3fjb2-f3fPUT-f3v5oh-f3fDA6-f2k3B7-f2kbJj-f2ktCA-f26oce-f2miD1-f26vB4-f2mBZW-f2kwYE-f28GDn-f2nxr3-f27UdH-f2o3tS-ehPuem-f3ucbA-4y387A

Answer (score 4):

Clockwise from top left:

1) [Halasuru Someshwara Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Halasuru_Someshwara_Temple.jpg)

2) [Kote Venkataramana Temple](https://iballrtw.com/2019/03/24/kote-venkataramana-temple/)

3) Mysore Palace (fairly sure, feel free to correct)

4) [Vidhana Soudha](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Attraction_Review-g297628-d2587646-Reviews-Vidhana_Soudha_and_Attara_Kacheri-Bengaluru_Bangalore_District_Karnataka.html)

5) [Shiva statue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murugeshpalya)

6) [Art of Living International Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Living_International_Center)